# How to replace row content in Excel in specific way?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice.org

Good morning everyone.
I have got a question to OpenOffice Excel 4.1.3.
I have got a xls file.
There are 4 columns.

```
symbol1 | content1 | symbol2 | content2
---------------------------------------
client  | empty    | seria   | aaa
code    | empty    | type    | ccc
seria   | empty    | code    | ddd
type    | empty    | client  | bbb
```

I need to insert appreciate data from column content2 which is in relation with symbol2 to column content1 which is in relation with column symbol1.
E.g.

```
client empty
```

should be

```
client bbb
```

Because client in symbol2 has got content2 bbb that's why content1 in client should be bbb.
So I would like to get:

```
symbol1 | content1 | symbol2 | content2
---------------------------------------
client  | bbb      | seria   | aaa
code    | ddd      | type    | ccc
seria   | aaa      | code    | ddd
type    | ccc      | client  | bbb
```

I don't know if it is possible to do it in OpenOffice Excel it could also be in Microsoft Excel.
I tried to use functions like "Replace", etc. but I don't know how to consider this relation with other column.
Thank you very much, have a nice day.

Comment: In Excel this can be done using `VLookUp`. As I've never worked with open office, not sure if its the same?

Comment: You could just name your range as well i.e. **`=VLOOKUP(A2,MyRange,2,0)`** (where `MyRange` is the name of your range). Now you can drag it and it will keep the range

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in range `A1:D5`, then in `Cell B2` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$5,2,0)
```

Drag/Copy down formula as required.

Comment: Everything is as you wrote, unfortunately I have got an error "Err:501".

Comment: @user2856064 - May be try `=VLOOKUP(A2;$C$2:$D$5;2;0)`

Comment: I have got "#N/A"

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is "=VLOOKUP(A2; $C$2:$D$5; 2; 0)".

Comment: This is what I gave you in the comments of my answer.